# ¿Cómo modificar Excel con origen de datos XML?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy usando la librería `ClosedXML` para modificar una plantilla de `excel` con un origen de datos `XML` que tengo por defecto ya guardada en otro lugar y la copio donde el usuario elija de esta manera

```
SaveFileDialog guardarArchivo = new SaveFileDialog();
guardarArchivo.Title = "Guardar Archivo como";
guardarArchivo.Filter = "Libro de Excel (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
guardarArchivo.ShowDialog();
```

Utilizo File.Copy para copiar y mantener el archivo origen en su lugar

```
File.Copy(rutaArchivooriginal, Ruta, true);
```

el archivo de `excel` contiene varias hojas las cuales para acceder a ella lo hago de esta manera

```
XLWorkbook LibroTrabajo = new XLWorkbook(Ruta);

var Hojas = LibroTrabajo.Worksheet("Hoja 1");
Hojas.Cell(2, 1).Value = "Hola mundo"; var Hojas2 = LibroTrabajo.Worksheet("Hoja 2");
Hojas2.Cell(3, 1).Value = "Hola mundo 2";
LibroTrabajo.Save();
```

El problema es que solo en la primera hoja del documento, cada celda me la asocia con el mapa `xml`, pero las demás celdas que se encuentran en las otras hojas no están asociada, lo que conlleva a que cuando exporto a `XML` y lo visualizo, la estructura solo me muestra los primeros datos de la primera hoja.

Y solo ocurre cuando estoy llenando los datos, porque si solo copio el documento de `excel` sin llenarlo, cada hoja y cada celda esta asociado a su variable `xml`. Como hago para que al llenar los datos, las celdas permanezcan con su origen de datos?. He intentado llenar el archivo de su lugar de origen y luego copiarlo ya con datos y sigue sin funcionar.